# What is a reliable way to obtain an optimism-correct AUC with confidence limits?

Tags: logistic, bootstrap, auc, somers-d, optimism

I have seen that Frank Harrell's `rms` package does not offer a CI for Somers Dxy (and subsequently the c-statistic/AUROC).

I am trying to look at a method with good performance and a plan to implement this properly, probably through R.

I know an optimism corrected AUC already involves a bootstrap, so would the best way to be to have a script run the optimism corrected AUC from a model, save it, and repeat the bootstrapping/correction of AUC with a loop of say B=500 times? Then just take the 2.5 and 97.5 quantiles?

What might be some issues with this? I don't think I have enough bootstrap/resampling expertise to foresee what problems might ensue.

1. is the above method reasonable?
2. what would be another method?
3. what issues or limitations are pertinent to numbers 1 and 2?

Comment: Is there a reason why CI estimates are omitted from rms?

Comment: As far as I am aware, you generally don't utilize the CI limits from each run. To build a bootstrap distribution, you resample and create a distribution of estimates (say the mean) but don't use the individual CI limits.